# Printing definition of dynamically defined Python class and method using type and setattr

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to dynamically define a class and its method using `type` and `setattr`. When I tried to print the content of the class using inspect.getsource, however, it doesn't find the class definition. What am I missing?

I was hoping the last line would print `class NewTest(): def prt(self): print("test") def requires(self): return 'success'` instead.

```
import inspect

class test():
    def prt(self):
        print("test")

def method1(cls):
    return 'success'

klass = type('NewTest', (test,), {})
setattr(klass, 'requires', classmethod(method1))

print(inspect.getsource(test))   #'class test():     def prt(self):        print("test")'
print(inspect.getsource(klass)) # {OSError}could not find class definition
```

Comment: Why would it print that? There is no such source code, the class was created dynamically

Comment: That's kind of what I was guessing. Is there a way to print its definition anyway? The class I'm actually creating dynamically is more complex, so I want to see how it looks like by printing it, as it's defined.

Comment: .... It's **not defined that way**. There *is no class definition*. There is no built-in utility to produce source code from a given class object, although, you may be able to hack something together. The source code must be available at compile time for inspect to work, I imagine.